# Collection View Layout Overload Arguments Problems Swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4

i have a bit of problem. I want to make gesture that open another view controller, but i have these error in my line of code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHgar.png)

First i add gesture :

```
titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
#selector(showChatController)))
```

And then i add the function code :

```
@objc func showChatController() {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
}
```

The First Error Is :

> Argument labels '(collectionViewLayout:)' do not match any available overloads

Because of that error , i get another error in another swift file [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK9yY.png)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Chat Room"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    setupInputComponents()
}
```

The Second Error is :

> Use of unresolved identifier 'collectionView

Anyone can help me with these problems thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is self explanatory, that the label is extra in the calling function

Update your existing line

```
let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

To

```
let chatLogController = ChatLogController(UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

For the second error,

probably, you have not defined the collectionView in your viewController and thus, showing the error.

Add the following line, if not previously there.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?
```

It will fix your issues. Try and share your results.

Comment: thanks for the answer , i update the code and give me another error " Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads "

Comment: i think i found the problem , because my titleView is defined UIView and simply changed to UIbutton fix the error . And i another problem is im wrapped my UITableView into NavigationController. Not sure whether this fix can be applied to all the case involving NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

if ChatLogController is UIViewController you can instantiate it by using following command:

let chatVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatLogControllerLabel") as! ChatLogController

and then pass it to pushViewController

dont forget to define ChatLogControllerLabel in StoryBoardID of the ViewController in storyboard

[image]

for the second error 
if you want to have collectioView identifier in your class the class should extend UICollectionViewController otherwise you have to declare it by yourself!

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i dont use storyboard . I use programmatically storyboard

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want to do? be aware that UItableview does not have collectionView identifier, may be you want to use tableView identifier

Comment: yeah , its my fault .my problem is im wrapped my UITableView into NavigationController. Not sure whether this fix can be applied to all the case involving NavigationController. But its fixed now thanks for explain